# merging two data frame with different age form

Tags: r

I have two data frame with different variables named "df" and df1. what I want to do is merging  df1 with "df" based on "gender", "age" and "district" in such a way that the age in "df" get given values of AC. for example, if AC is in age group 20-24, all age in "df" which is between 20 to 24 get that same value of AC. thank you in advance.

```
df<- 
   district residence gender  age   weight  id
      
        1         1      1    12   26.8     1
        2         2      2    14   21.4     2
        3         1      1    20   24.2     3
        4         2      2    23   35.8     4
        5         1      1    31   42.3     5
        6         2      2    16   25.2     6
        7         1      1    22   35.3     7
        8         2      2    45   25.3     8
        9         1      1    48   36.2     9
       10         2      2    39   35.5    10


df1<-
      district age    gender   AC
         1   15-19      2    0.0301 
         2   20-24      2    0.0934 
         3   25-29      2    0.108  
         4   30-34      2    0.0894 
         5   35-39      2    0.0444 
         6   40-44      2    0.00945
         7   45-49      2    0.00226
         8   15-19      2    0.0258 
         9   20-24      2    0.0701 
        10   25-29      2    0.0827
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the age column of `df1` into two columns and use `fuzzyjoin`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>%
  separate(age, c('start', 'end'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE) %>% 
  fuzzy_right_join(df, 
                   by = c('district', 'gender', 'start' = 'age', 'end' = 'age'), 
                   match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a poor minimal example, because there are no such matches in your data. I have modified your data a little bit. Also note that you have some ages in df for which there are no labels in df1.

```
df$district=1
df1$district=1

df$age1=cut(
  df$age,
  c(0,as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(unique(df1$age),"-"),"[[",2)))),
  labels=sort(unique(df1$age))
)

merge(
  df,
  df1,
  by.x=c("gender","age1","district"),
  by.y=c("gender","age","district")
)

  gender  age1 district residence age weight id      AC
1      2 15-19        1         2  14   21.4  2 0.03010
2      2 15-19        1         2  14   21.4  2 0.02580
3      2 15-19        1         2  16   25.2  6 0.03010
4      2 15-19        1         2  16   25.2  6 0.02580
5      2 20-24        1         2  23   35.8  4 0.07010
6      2 20-24        1         2  23   35.8  4 0.09340
7      2 35-39        1         2  39   35.5 10 0.04440
8      2 45-49        1         2  45   25.3  8 0.00226
```

Comment: thank you so much. how can I consider a range of ages? in your codes you start with age 0( c(0,as.numeric(unlist(lapply...), I want start with 0 to 100.

Comment: @mehmo I don't understand. In my code I set the lower limit of the first interval to 0, you can change that to any other number. My code is currently written such that it is based on the existing intervals in df1, if those intervals change the merge will also change.